# Unreal Engine 4 - Issue with TArrays and Visual Studio intellisense

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense, unreal-engine4, visual-assist-x

I've faced an issue with **intellisense in Visual Studio** while working with **TArrays**. The problem is that intellisense is not able to find TArray's native functions like "Add()", "Emplace()", "Empty()", "Num()" etc and even iterate over it (cause "begin()" is not found as well). It's not even work with simple types e.g.

```
TArray<int> some_array;
some_array.Add(5);//class TArray<%params%> has no member "Add"
```

[image: screenshot visual studio]

I've checked this issue with other containers like TMap and seems like it is ok.
Reproduced both with VS and VAX intellisense. Anyway, it's quite annoying and makes intellisense highlighting useless. Compilation is ok.
Seems like the issue appeared after update of VS, as it was working before update. Currently I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.4.3 (and yeah, i didn't update it for a while, so probably the issue appeared not in the latest version of VS)

Any ideas?
Thanks.

[link to ue4 forum original issue page](https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/c-gameplay-programming/1713049-issue-with-tarrays-and-visual-studio-intellisense)

Comment: Did you include `#include "Containers/Array.h"`? It may hint intellisense that they in fact exist.

Comment: Hawky, thanks for your reply.
I've tried your suggestion, but it didn't solve my problem. Anyway, I've already fixed the issue. Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like I found a root cause of this issue as well as solution for it.
Issue was caused by Visual Studio cached files. I've deleted .vs folder in the directory of my project , reopen VS and it reindexed all project files from scratch. After this procedure the problem is gone.